# how do I create glass material and lens material similar to the glass camera panel in image?

Tags: materials, procedural, glass

[image]

Hi, I am trying to create a glass material that is similar to the one I posted below...
How do I achieve a similar effect, in eevee?

[image]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: What part are you talking about, and have you tried to set the Transmission to 1, switch from Opaque to Alpha Blend and so on?

Comment: I am trying to get the camera frame glass for the iphone to look as close as possible to the one in the image....